# Flagging dialog has slightly misleading text

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, design, flagging

I flagged a post for closure (not as a duplicate). When I went again to the flagging dialog it correctly displayed that `you have already raised this type of flag` but this text was also displayed under the `it is a duplicate` option, which is misleading because I didn't flag it as a dupe.

I'll not term this behavior as incorrect (but misleading) because I understand that even after flagging for closure (as OT or Dupe), I can still flag the same post as spam, vlq, etc. However, I believe that the text should be displayed under the appropriate option.

[image]

Comment: This is by design. You can read about it [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199188/misleading-text-in-flag-dialog-you-have-already-raised-this-flag-when-i-didn).

Comment: @dcaswell Thanks for providing the link.